# Which Vaishnavite sects have the concept of "Nitya Suri"?

Tags: vaishnavism, nityasuri

I know that SriVaishnavites have this concept.  What exactly does it mean and do other Vaishnavite sects have it?

Comment: I think the concept of Nitya suri in Sri Vaishnavism comes from the Rig vedic hymn - tad vishnoh paramam padam sada pasyanti soorayah... Nitya suri is one who is eternally liberated.

Comment: I think Nitya Suri is just another word used for Parshadas.